# How do debug non-valid Django form?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

Inspired from [a](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3/), [b](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/) and other sources I am trying to upload a file via a Django Form in the following way:

**HTML:**

```
[..]
<script>
  $(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
});
</script>
[..]
<form id="form" 
          method="POST" 
          action="/licenses/uploadLicense" 
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-file leftMenuButton">
     Upload License <input id="filecontent" type="file">
  </span>
</form>
[..]
```

**View:**

```
@login_required
def uploadLicense(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadLicenseForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() :
            license = LicenseModel.objects.create()
            license.setContent(request.FILES['content'])
            license.save()
            return redirect(main)
```

My line `form.is_valid()` returns false and when debugging inside that method I found the following errors: `{'filecontent': [u'This field is required.']}`. So for some reason the file is not being uploaded it seems. But how do I go on from here and figure out why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't given your input element a `name` attribute, so the browser won't send any data.

Comment: Wow, is it even possible to figure that one out without knowing about it? I honestly thought `id` would be enough...